# CLeditor uses the HTML 'align' attribute.  How can I change that to CSS 'text-align'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alignment, wysiwyg, cleditor

I've set up the CLeditor on a site I'm working on.  Currently I'm setting it up so that as you type and edit within the editor, you can see a live preview of the results just above it, a lot like what you get when typing a StackOverflow question, though much more basic.

It works by simply copying the inner HTML of the iframe contents to another place on the page.  However I've run into an annoying issue.  When I use the alignment buttons (left, center, right), it adds the attribute `align="right"`, for example, to the selected text.  While it works in the editor, it does not work on the page itself, probably because that attribute is pretty much obsolete.

...

I actually figured out how to get around this issue while typing this question. Still, I'll post this question with my solution.  Plus I have a relevant question to add to this.

Originally I tried applying the following CSS to the page:

```
div[align="right"] {
    text-align:right!important;
    }
```

This worked for initially loading the data onto the page, but while dynamically changing alignment in the editor, the live preview was not reflecting the changes.  I thought at first that this was because the styles were applied at load time only.

Well, that was a brain fart because I know better than that.  The real problem was that I was selecting a DIV element and the align attribute isn't necessarily applied to a DIV.  Changing `div[align="right"]` to `*[align="right"]` works perfectly.

However, even though I found a workaround for this specific issue, I still can't figure out how the cleditor builds the HTML output for the iframe.  Where does the `align` attribute come from in the code and how does it know to put it (and all of the other elements/attributes) into the HTML?  If I had a way of manipulating this, I could simply tell it to use inline CSS for the alignment rather than the deprecated `align` HTML attribute.  Please note that I do not wish to enable the cleditor's built-in "useCSS" feature.

Thanks for any information you can share, and please do not downvote this question just because I already solved the initial problem.  I want this to be able to help others if they run into the same issue.  (I'll also post my answer as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Applying the following CSS to the live-preview of the page works perfectly:

```
*[align="right"] {
  text-align:right!important;
}
```

Don't forget to do the same for left and center as well.